Problem with dual boot, grub
I'm getting grub console screen every time I restart my computer, but when I exit it shows me this Windows Boot Manager screen. I'm new to Linux and have an Ubuntu dual boot.


hi, welcome to this forum! as the screenshot is not in English, it'll be difficult for the community to assist you. however, it looks like your grub detects only windows OS, which means you're dual-booting. please update your question with more details.

What brand/model system? Some require settings in UEFI setting to change boot order (HP) or "trust" ubuntu boot entry(Acer). Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
